# Choosing the contour for solving the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{i-1}}{e^x-1}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

My initial goal was to calculate $\zeta(i)$ through the formula $$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx.$$ In the meantime I found the value of $\Gamma(i)\approx -0.1549-0.498i$, and even the end result $\zeta(i)\approx 0.0033-0.4182i$. Still, I'm left baffled with how to solve this integral using residues:

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{i-1}}{e^x-1}dx,$$

which arises from the formula, and is approximately $I=\zeta(i)\Gamma(i)\approx -0.2088+0.0631 i$.

The $e^x-1$ in the denominator suggests that at $x=0$ there is an essential singularity, and I'm not sure how to treat the $x^{i-1}$ factor (as a branch cut or something else, like $\exp((i-1)\ln x)$). Is it better to choose a keyhole contour because of the branch cut, a rectangular contour because of the $e^x$, or an exotic contour that magically incorporates both of them?

Comment: The integral converges whenever $\Re\left(\, s\, \right) > 1$.

Comment: for computing $\zeta(i)$ you should better use something else, for example $\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} + 1/2 + s\int_1^\infty (\lfloor x \rfloor - x - 1/2) x^{-s-1}dx$ for $Re(s) > -1$. And $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ has a simple pole at $x=0$, but $x^{i-1}$ has a branch cut there. Applying the change of variable $x = e^u$, the branch cut is removed, and with the residue theorem (using the fact that $f(u) = \frac{e^{s u}}{e^{e^u}-1}, f(u+2i\pi) = e^{2i \pi s}f(u)$) it yields the functional equation.

Comment: The keyhole contour is not useful here since when $\cos(\phi)\le 0$, $\lim_{R\to \infty }e^{Re^{i\phi}}\ne \infty$.

Comment: (and I'm 99% sure what I wrote is how Riemann discovered the functional equation)

Comment: @user1952009 that's some interesting stuff you propose. Would you mind elaborating it a bit more and posting as an answer?